# How to echo &#8377; in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display Indian rupee sign using html code ₹ The html code is echo'd in php. everything working except the rupee symbol is not displaying.

I tried using other currency symbol and its working fine. I am using chrome(Up to date). Why the Indian currency symbol is not displaying?

```html
echo'<div class="uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top">&#8377;</div>';
```

Comment: Is your page defined as UTF8? `<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>`

Comment: Be noticed that some browsers (Chrome for example) still does not support full range, see here for more:
http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp

Comment: @RiggsFolly — That doesn't matter. There aren't any UTF-8 characters in the source code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem when I test that. It outputs `<div class="uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top">&#8377;</div>` which [renders fine](http://jsbin.com/hacefu/1/edit?html,output). You have a lot of class names there, maybe you have some CSS which is hiding the rendered content.

Comment: I tried <meta charset="UTF-8"> still not displaying

Comment: Give us a test case the reproduces your problem.  Currently, this question is unsolvable.

Comment: I tried using another currency code &#8355; and its working. Why indian rupee symbol is not working?

Comment: please post ur output.

Comment: @RockyHandsome Last attempt to help. Your test case does not reproduce the problem for us. Thus, it is no help. Asking us why your setup doesn't work for you won't yield results, when we can't reproduce your setup. So if you want this question to be answered, you'll need to work with us, and give us what we need: an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Font Awesome Icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/inr/)

Display symbol:

```
echo'<div class="uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i></div>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code with UTF8

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

```html
echo "<div class='uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top'>&#8377;</div>";
```

Comment: `&#8377;` only includes ASCII characters. Telling the browser that it is UTF-8 won't make a difference. (The character encoding matters for parsing the *source code* not the rendered result)

Comment: you're right though, his problem is that the document is not loaded as utf-8 , once that's done, all he needs to do is echo '₹';

Answer (score -1):

try closing php tags, e.g :

```
?>
<div class="uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top">&#8377;</div> 
<?php //your stuff
```

Comment: That won't make any difference. Why do you think it would?

Answer (score -1):

I know what is your problem. PHP only echo your text because you have used ' instead ".PHP doesn't convert this string. It should be:

```html
echo "<div class=\"uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top\">&#8377;</div>";
```

Comment: There are no PHP variables or PHP escape sequences in the string. The only difference that using `"` will make is to force you to escape the `"` inside the string.